# Team Fortress 2 - Low Frame Rate

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, graphics, games, steam

I have observed a strange problem with Team Fortress 2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

**Note** This does not seem to affect the single player mode, only multiplayer. I can play on the single player training mode for an arbitary time and the problem does not seem to reappear.

Sometimes my game gets stuck with very low frame rates. This can happen when I initially connect to a game server, in which case I have to quit the game and reload it, or during a game. The frame rate will drop and get stuck at 1 or 2 frames per second.

What I find strange about this is that this can happen after I have been playing for a few minutes.

I will add more info as I learn more.

Has anyone else see anything like this?

My Specs

CPU: Intel Core i7 920
GPU: Nvidia GTX 260
Driver version: 340.96 (Recommended as per driver search on nvidia website)

**Steps to Reproduce**

[Currently unsure about this]

- Boot PC
- Login, run steam, run TF2
- Search for games on "Casual"
- Join game (takes a very long time - several minutes - how long should it take?)
- Play for approx 5 minutes - suddenly frame rate stuck in low frame rate mode
- Or play for 0 minutes, game is already stuck in low FPS mode.

When quiting a match, the fps remains low, even in the welcome/home screen.

Also the "sound gets messed up" when in low fps mode - this is another way to tell something went wrong.

My Nvidia profile is set to "prefer maximum performance". psensor reports that my GPU usage is 100 % when stuck in low FPS mode.

I don't think running psensor is the cause of the issue - problem occurs when psensor is not running also.

Comment: Did you install the proprietary nvidia drivers? Are they loaded correctly? Do you experience those problems with other games, too?

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann I installed drivers via the additional drivers tool.